# GAE error: An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.Get()

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

My App Engine project has 4 services. The default service sometimes starts throwing this runtime error on all HTTP requests to jsp or servlet. Daily my service becomes down for almost 15-20 minutes,2 or 3 times a day. My other service on this project is working fine.

I am using Google Cloud Datastore with Objectify 5 and Guava 18 library.

This is the stack I got in errors.

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$UnknownException: An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.Get().
at com.google.apphosting.utils.runtime.ApiProxyUtils.statusException (ApiProxyUtils.java:209)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.runtime.ApiProxyUtils.getRpcError (ApiProxyUtils.java:130)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.setRpcError (ApiProxyImpl.java:636)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.failure (ApiProxyImpl.java:622)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.http.HttpApiHostClient.communicationFailure (HttpApiHostClient.java:203)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.http.JettyHttpApiHostClient$Listener.onComplete (JettyHttpApiHostClient.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete (ResponseNotifier.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete (ResponseNotifier.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange.notifyFailureComplete (HttpExchange.java:269)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange.abort (HttpExchange.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpConversation.abort (HttpConversation.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.abort (HttpRequest.java:735)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.abort (HttpDestination.java:271)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.PoolingHttpDestination.failed (PoolingHttpDestination.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.DuplexConnectionPool$1.failed (DuplexConnectionPool.java:159)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Promise$Wrapper.failed (Promise.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient$1$1.failed (HttpClient.java:588)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractHttpClientTransport.connectFailed (AbstractHttpClientTransport.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractHttpClientTransport.connect (AbstractHttpClientTransport.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient$1.connect (HttpClient.java:593)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient$1.succeeded (HttpClient.java:570)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient$1.succeeded (HttpClient.java:563)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SocketAddressResolver$Async.lambda$resolve$1 (SocketAddressResolver.java:181)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.keys (SelectorImpl.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.size (ManagedSelector.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.chooseSelector (SelectorManager.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.connect (SelectorManager.java:207)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractHttpClientTransport.connect (AbstractHttpClientTransport.java:118)
```

Comment: Do you see any other errors accompanying this one? Like DeadlineExceededError or OutOfMemoryError? This might happen due to out of memory errors, for example, as it might take some time for the managing service to make sure the instance is not recoverable and needs to be killed. During this time it will still try to handle requests and you might see various errors.One of the tricks is adding `<env-variables>
  <env-var name="GAE_JAVA_OPTS" value="-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError" />
</env-variables>` to your `appengine-web.xml` file, thus instance will be killed immediately after this error.

Comment: Yes.i often see these errors also DeadlineExceededError or OutOfMemoryError an i added the environment variable in appengine-web.xml. Today i didn't see this error maybe it solved my problem.Should i also go for F2 instance class instead of F1 instace class which is default ? What do you suggest??

Comment: Hi, it's hard to suggest you to increase your instances resources without looking at the actual usage of your instances. In this situation my best advice would be just check your instance usage and if you feel that they are overloaded increase the instance class and re-check. Also if you are eligible for gcp support open an internal ticket with [Google Cloud Platform technical support](https://cloud.google.com/support/)

Comment: I'm also facing the same while running the test cases on the local machine, what solution worked for you? before I dig thought of checking.